# loading symbol not appearing on button click

Tags: iphone, xcode

```
-(IBAction)addtocontacts:(id)sender
{
    HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    HUD.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"Saving_data", @"");

    //added my validation here
   [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(insertDetails) withObject:nil];
}
-(void) insertDetails
{
  //save contact details in database
[HUD hide:YES];
    UIAlertView *alertview=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Contact account details added" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alertview show];
}
```

I have added loading symbol on `SaveButton` click.I am not getting loading symbol.How do I make it appear until I get alert message.

Comment: When is `HUD` declared?

Comment: Please follow naming convention, I feel HUD is a constant or a className

Comment: Just comment the `[HUD hide:YES];` and check whether the HUD is displayed or not. If displaying then you need a timer or something to stop the HUD. If not displaying then the issue is withe the HUD

Comment: it is class name.I declared it in .h file.

Comment: i did so.it is displaying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add HUD on top most layer. Example if you have tableview on top of view. Then add it on tableview. In my case I am adding HUD on tableviews and its working fine

Comment: [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.my_tableView animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

it is because you are instantly hiding the HUD in insertDetails.

```
   -(IBAction)addtocontacts:(id)sender
    {
        HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
        HUD.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"Saving_data", @"");

        //added my validation here
       [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(insertDetails) withObject:nil];
    }

    -(void) insertDetails
    {
      //save contact details in database
   // [HUD hide:YES]; remove it
        UIAlertView *alertview=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Contact account details added" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertview show];
    }
```

and instead download the newer version of MBProgressHUD and use the following Method

```
- (IBAction)addtocontacts:(id)sender {
    // The hud will dispable all input on the view (use the higest view possible in the view hierarchy)
    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
    [self.view addSubview:HUD];

    // Regiser for HUD callbacks so we can remove it from the window at the right time
    HUD.delegate = self;

    // Show the HUD while the provided method executes in a new thread
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(myTask) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
}
```

and implement the delegate method.

## MBProgressHUDDelegate methods

```
- (void)hudWasHidden:(MBProgressHUD *)hud {
    // Remove HUD from screen when the HUD was hidded
    [HUD removeFromSuperview];
    [HUD release];
    HUD = nil;
}
```